# Assist a rookie with Range Function

Tags: python, range

```
decimal = 10
for k in range(decimal):
    print(k)
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

How would I edit it so the output would become:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

I'm assuming to add a +1 or something somewhere but I'm not sure how :'(

Comment: There are only four places in your code where you *could* add a `+ 1`; why don't you try each and see what happens?

Answer (score 4):

You could use

```
range(1,decimal+1)
```

or simply

```
print(k+1)
```